# Derive instance from field in record

Tags: haskell, deriving

Example code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

module Sample where

class Sample a where
  isA :: a -> Bool
  isB :: a -> Bool
  isC :: a -> Bool

data X =
  X

instance Sample X where
  isA = undefined
  isB = undefined
  isC = undefined

data Wrapper = Wrapper
  { x :: X
  , i :: Int
  }

instance Sample Wrapper where
  isA Wrapper {x} = isA x
  isB Wrapper {x} = isB x
  isC Wrapper {x} = isC x
```

Here, I have some class that is implemented by `X`, and then another record `Wrapper` containing `X`.

I want `Wrapper` to derive the `Sample` instance, through its field `x`.

I know I can do so by getting the field and calling it myself for each function, as shown.

Is there some flag or some method to do so automatically or once only?

This seems similar to `DerivingVia` and `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`, but both seem to target `newtype` or coercible types only

Comment: I've changed `A` to `X` here to avoid ambiguity with `isA`. Feel free to roll it back if you don't think it improves the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some strategies that do not require any extensions, but trade some upfront cost for the ease of deriving these classes.

Note that since `Sample` is not a newtype, there's no guarantee it will only hold one `X` and not two, more or a variable amount (`Maybe X`? `Either X X`?). Therefore, as you'll see, your options have to make the choice of `X` inside the structure explicit, and that is a likely reason for an extension that derives this automatically to *not* exist.

### Derive one function instead of many

To satisfy `Sample`, we really need an `X`. Let's make that a typeclass:

```
class HasX t where
  getX :: t -> X

class Sample t where
  isA :: t -> Bool
  isB :: t -> Bool
  isC :: t -> Bool
  default isA :: HasX t => t -> Bool
  isA = isA . getX
  default isB :: HasX t => t -> Bool
  isB = isB . getX
  default isC :: HasX t => t -> Bool
  isC = isC . getX

instance HasX Wrapper where
  getX = x

instance Sample Wrapper -- no implementation necessary
```

### Derive via generics

Let's say we want to only work on the records that have `X` as the first field. To match the type structure, we can use [GHC.Generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). Here we add a way for `HasX` to default to the first field:

```
class HasX t where
  getX :: t -> X
  default getX :: (Generic a, HasX (Rep a)) => t -> X
  getX = getX . from

instance HasX (M1 D d (M1 C c (M1 S s (Rec0 X) :*: ff))) o where
  getX (M1 (M1 ((M1 (K1 x)) :*: _))) = x
```

The last instance for `HasX` matches any record (`M1 D`) with a single constructor (`M1 C`), which has more than one (`:*:`) field (`M1 S`), the first field being of type (`Rec0`) `X`.

(Yes, the generic instance is unwieldy. Edits welcome.)

(To see the exact representation of the generic type of `Wrapper`, inspect `Rep Wrapper` in the GHCi console.)

Now the instance for `Wrapper` can be written as:

```
data Wrapper = Wrapper
  { x :: X
  , i :: Int
  }
  deriving (Generic, HasX, Sample)
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, the first example requires the language flag `DefaultSignatures`

Comment: The other one probably requires a few, too.